# Is it correct to say "preselecting examination"

Tags: expressions, translation

I am applying for a scholarship and I need to write an application letter for the preselections. I filled the subject field by
"Application for [name of the scholarship] scholarship preselecting examination"

But then I get confused when I start searching for "preselecting" in the dictionary, I can't find any name or adjective under this title, thought I think I need one for the expression to be grammatically correct. Can you help me to clarify my confusion? If "preselecting examination" is wrong, what is the correct word, knowing that I try to translate the french expression "concours de préselection".

Thank you.

Comment: tru preselect**ion**. [definition MW ](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preselect)

Comment: In principle you *could* use the "gerund noun" form ***preselecting*** as an attributive noun before ***examination***, but in practice native speakers would always prefer the more explicitly "nouny" form ***preselection***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Preselection examination" would be more accurate than "preselecting examination," but neither sounds natural to me. The usage also strikes me as redundant. I'd be inclined to omit it from the subject line: "Application for [Name of Scholarship]" should be sufficient in this context. On a side note, the decision (even if it's technically a preselection) will be made by a selection committee -- sometimes called a search committee.